# Setting an ip address to the embedded system from html by means of executing a command setenv ipaddr "textbox"

Tags: linux, cgi, html-lists, embedded-linux

How to invoke a linux command prompt from html page using shell scripting...? 
For exp:

I am new to the group and am looking for some quick advice/help in writing a cgi script or scripts. I unfortunately don't have the time/resources to visit a course or read tons of documentations or books.

I have written several shell scripts in ksh bash etc. to perform various tasks on several solaris and linux servers. Some of these scripts take input from the user which is read in as shell positional parameters. I am now required to make these scripts available via a web interface. I need a way to get input from the user and pass that input to my shell script. The input from the user is short. Usually an ip-address or customer name.
What are your suggestions?

Comment: A CGI script is a program which is called by the web-server, and has data filled into environment variables, and writes the HTML to `stdout`. So to make a CGI script which changes the IP address, just make a shell script which reads the new address from the correct environment variable, calls e.g. `ifconfig` and uses `echo` to create the resulting web-page.

Comment: I suggest you start by just experimenting, for example make a script which `echo` all environment variables so you get a good list of the variables involved.

Comment: can you provide me some example code, I have to execute a commond, "fw_setenv ipaddr 'IP'", this commond as to take the input IP from HTML page and by onclick submit it as to execute the commond.

Comment: See e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/BashShellCgi.html). There are many tutorials if you just do a search for e.g. "cgi script shell tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

Changing the IP address requires root privileges. Thus a CGI executed by the webserver requires these rights.

So either you run the webserver as root (which is really bad) or you need to develop some custom intermediate scripts that invoke the scripts you already have which have the suid bit.

The tutorial proposed by Joachim Pileborg can be good to develop the intermediate script without having to learn a new language such as php.